# Makefile: Save a variable during execution time

Tags: makefile

I'm using Makefiles with "make" for a lot of things like starting / stopping / configuring services I've written. Sometimes I'd like to read an input from the user. The only ways I know are either make the user pass his input with NAME=VALUE when executing make, or by putting a command like `read -p "setting X: " var ; echo $$var` into the Makefile.

NAME=VALUE has the disadvantage that the user must manually set it and I can't "ask" him to enter a value. `read` has the disadvantage that the read value can not (or I don't know how) be saved in a variable and so it can't be used multiple times.

Is there a way to read user input into a variable during executing a specific makefile target? (I don't want to put `FILE ?= 'read -p "value: " var ; echo $$var'` in the header because the value is only needed for one target, and when I put that line in the target itself, I get the error "/bin/bash: FILE: Command not found. ".

Answer (score 0):

I use intermediate files for this purpose.

```
INPUT = dialog --inputbox 80 10 10

all: case1 case2

case1: read-input
    echo $(shell cat read-input) in case 1

case2: read-input
    echo $(shell cat read-input) in case 2


.INTERMEDIATE: read-input
read-input:
    $(INPUT) 2>$@
```